# PHP - adding only distinct value to an array in foreach loop not working

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating an associative array in Wordpress from user meta like this:

```
$users = get_users();
$allMeta = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
  $allMeta[$user->ID] = get_user_meta($user->ID);
}

$metaValues = ['region', 'department', 'industry', 'company'];
$filteredMeta = [];
foreach($allMeta as $meta){
  foreach($meta as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $metaValues)) {
      $filteredMeta[$key][] = reset($value);
    }
  }
}
```

The result of it is this array:

```
$filteredMeta = [
        "department": [
            "Administrasjon",
            "Logistikk",
            "Administrasjon",
            "Administrasjon",
            "Logistikk",
            "Logistikk"
        ],
        "region": [
            "Oslo",
            "Oslo",
            "Oslo",
            "Oslo",
            "Oslo",
            "Akershus"
        ],
        "industry": [
            "Bane",
            "Bane",
            "Bane",
            "Buss",
            "Buss",
            "Bane"
        ],
        "company": [
            "NSB",
            "NSB",
            "NSB",
            "NSB",
            "NSB"
        ]
    ]
```

I have tried by getting only distinct values in that array by adding additional condition `!in_array($value, $filteredMeta[$key])` in the foreach loop:

```
foreach($allMeta as $meta){
      foreach($meta as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $metaValues) && !in_array(reset($value), $filteredMeta[$key])) {
          $filteredMeta[$key][] = reset($value);
        }
      }
    }
```

But, that didn't work, I wouldn't get anything back, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `foreach($value as $key => $value) {` - `$value` two times? You should choose another var name for the values.

Comment: Even when I set them to have different names, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
$filteredMeta = [];
foreach($allMeta as $meta){
  foreach($meta as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $metaValues)) {
      $filteredMeta[$key][] = reset($value);
    }
  }
}
```

To

```
$filteredMeta = [];

foreach($allMeta as $meta){

foreach($meta as $key => $value) {

// From here we modify
// we got valid value which is in list of our interest
if(in_array($key, $metaValues)) {

  // some variable to save value to be added
  $tmpvar = reset($value);

  // status not interested call several times same function so
  $status = isset($filteredMeta[$key]);

  // if key does not exist in array before, meaning first time OR
  // key is set, value not exists before - for duplicate check
  if(
     !$status || 
     ( $status  && !in_array($tmpvar,  $filteredMeta[$key]) )
   ){

      // if key exists before then append 
      if($status){

         $filteredMeta[$key][] =  $tmpvar;

      }else{
            // we need to create array
           $filteredMeta[$key] = array($tmpvar); 
      }

    }

} // end of in_array

 } 
} // close of top foreach
```